# Why can touch change only all times, or nothing when not owner

Tags: files, permissions, timestamps, stat, touch

We have a file `foobar` not owned by me, but it is in my group:

```
$ ll
total 4,0K
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root hbogert 4 jan 19 12:27 foobar
```

I can touch it and it will update all times:

```
 $ stat foobar
  File: 'foobar'
  Size: 4           Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 4869333     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: ( 1000/ hbogert)
Access: 2017-01-19 12:27:04.499412133 +0100
Modify: 2017-01-19 12:27:04.499412133 +0100
Change: 2017-01-19 12:27:04.499412133 +0100
 Birth: -


 $ touch foobar


 $ stat foobar 
  File: 'foobar'
  Size: 4           Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 4869333     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: ( 1000/ hbogert)
Access: 2017-01-19 12:32:04.375412133 +0100
Modify: 2017-01-19 12:32:04.375412133 +0100
Change: 2017-01-19 12:32:04.375412133 +0100
 Birth: -
```

However, when I just want to change the modification time, it fails:

```
$ touch -m foobar
touch: setting times of 'foobar': Operation not permitted
```

Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The behaviour is expected, if rather non-obvious. At least on my system, `touch` does

```
utimensat(0, NULL, NULL, 0)
```

in the first case (`touch file`), and

```
utimensat(0, NULL, [UTIME_OMIT, UTIME_NOW], 0)
```

in the second (`touch -m file`). The first call is short-hand for "set the access and modification times to the current time"; the second says "leave the access time alone and change the modification time to the current time".

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/utimensat.html) says

> Only a process with the effective user ID equal to the user ID of the file, or with write access to the file, or with appropriate privileges may use *futimens*() or *utimensat*() with a null pointer as the *times* argument or with both *tv_nsec* fields set to the special value UTIME_NOW. Only a process with the effective user ID equal to the user ID of the file or with appropriate privileges may use *futimens*() or *utimensat*() with a non-null *times* argument that does not have both *tv_nsec* fields set to UTIME_NOW and does not have both *tv_nsec* fields set to UTIME_OMIT.

(`times` is the third argument to `utimensat()`). `touch file` falls under the first set of access restrictions: any write access to the file allows the access and modification times to be changed to "now". `touch -m file` falls under the second set of access restrictions: you need to be `root` or the owner of the file to be able to change the access and modification times to values which are not either both "now" or both "unchanged".

There are other ways of changing the access and/or modification times to "now" on files you don't own but can read or write:

- reading a file will update the access time only;
- writing a file (*without* reading it) will update the modification time only.

Comment: I have a feeling that some Unix/Linux variants do not allow you to set a modification time later than an access time as a file needs to be accessed to be modified.

Comment: Yeah. Its weird. I did the same test with a file that is owned by root and my user group, and `664` as permission set. Can confirm that i will be able to change all timestamps, but not "access only" or "modify only" - And taking a look at `touch` source code, this is the expected behavior on some systems... it will fall to group and other permissions when changing all timestamps, but will not allow one of the timestamps alone.

Comment: Forgot the source code link - https://gist.github.com/JoshCheek/1224782

Comment: @nwildner The canonical source is also available [directly from GNU](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/touch.c).

Comment: @nwildner Where do you see the behaviour you're describing in the code? `touch` just delegates to `utimensat()` for the time change itself, and `utimensat()` enforces the rules. There's just [one special case](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/touch.c#n160) to avoid errors when setting both times to "now".

Comment: There is a place on the code, before a variable declaration that states: `If true, the only thing we have to do is change both the modification and access time to the current time, so we don't have to own the file, just be able to read and write it` This clearly seems to be "If i do not own, search for group and others permission". And, i did the following test to comfirm this behavior: Created a file `/tmp/test` owned by `root:root` and `666` permission. Guest what? I can modify all timestamps with `touch /tmp/test`, but cant `touch -m /tmp/test` neither `touch -a /tmp/test`...

Comment: @nwildner OK, but that's just describing the behaviour; I'd taken your comment as meaning that `touch` itself was implementing the behaviour (with explicit permission checks).

Comment: Yeah, i was just adding more information to your answer ;)

Comment: I dont understand the 3rd case: "the caller must have appropriate privileges." What kind of privileges would suffice?

Comment: @hbogert Typically, "have appropriate privileges" would mean "be `root`" (or have the appropriate POSIX capabilities, I don't know off-hand if there is one in this case).